# Getting started with a cocos2d v2.0 image warp app / ccgrid / ccactiongrid

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have to make an app that takes an image of a face, allows the user to indicate the location of main features like eyes and mouth and then warp the image to give a particular expression (smile / frown).

My thinking is that I could use a few component ccgrids for the mouth / eyes separately and then combine these to make a live ccgrid to be applied with a ccactiongrid.

First of all is this a sensible way to approach this?

Secondly, I can't find any examples of how to work with ccgrid objects or ccactiongrids. Are there any examples out there that I'm missing or could someone give me a crash course?

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: I don't know any CCGrid tutorials. You can use the existing code and learn from it. If that's too steep a learning curve then look for general algorithms that perform image processing. Also ask yourself if you're in way over your head and maybe consider simpler solutions or look for already existing image manipulation libraries that you could plug into your app. Besides that, I doubt that using CCGrid actions will give you the effect you desire (from, smile, etc) since they're not permanent image modification tools but rather animation tools. Further reading: http://tinyurl.com/bp6eaxv

Comment: Ok, I know Cocos2D in general. Looking through the code I'm thinking that a CCGrid3DAction subclass is the way to go as I can take e.g. CCWaves as a starting point but do the maths my own way.